# instabot bot.searchUsers() returns True instead of value

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm using [instabot](https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot) python module to work with instagram API, I'm trying to search a username but when I try It always returns True instead of result value, this is my code:

```
bot = Bot()    
bot.login(username="mytest_user", password="my_pass")
users = bot.searchUsers(query="test")
print "==========%s" % users
```

and it returns:

```
2017-10-26 01:23:48,153 - INFO - Login success as mytest_user!
========== True
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bot.searchUsers() returns boolean.

your function must like this:

```
bot.searchUsers('your_query_to_search_usernames')
jsondata = bot.LastJson
for username in jsondata['users']:
      print(username['username']
```

It will work.